# Evaluate the max size for a spark broadcast variable

Tags: apache-spark, global-variables, broadcast

I'm trying to measure the max size of variable I can broadcast using spark broadcast.

I didn't find any explanation regarding this issue.

did someone measure it? does spark has configuration for broadcast size?

Answer (score 2):

Limit for broadcasting has now been increased to 8 GB. you can find the details [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L101).

Answer (score 0):

It's currently ~2GB. Anything you broadcast is converted into java byte array during serialization and as java arrays have max size Integer.MAX_VALUE you get this limit. There may currently be some effort increasing this limit: [SPARK-6235](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235)