# Find nearest stores given single store location + what is max broadcast variable size in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read a file which has all the grocery stores into RDD. Goal is to find out the nearest 500 stores for a given grocery store and do some processing. 
For example if a store is taken, I'll have to find all the stores in that city. If I do map on the RDD, I get single store to the transform function. How do I get all the stores in that function.

Snippet

```
def getNearestStores(store):
    stores_city = stores.filter("city="+store.city)
    return (store.id,stores_city.count()) 
stores = sc.textFile("stores.json").map(getNearestStores).count()
```

This is the simple code snippet. Stores.json is a huge file

1) How can I get the nearest 500 stores, presumably by using the stores.json, in the getNearestStores function?

2) What is the max broadcast variable size in PySpark?

Comment: if I understand the task from the code, it's get count of all stores in same city for every store...  if that's right, I wouldn't use a broadcast variable...  i'd do something like this on an RDD[Store] to get an RDD[(store_id, count stores in same city)]...  `rdd.keyBy(_.city).groupByKey.flatMap{ case (city, iter_stores) => iter_stores.map(one_store => (one_store.id, iter_stores.size)) }`

Comment: @kmh its not just the count. There is additional processing to be performed.  Here is the full usecase: for every store, fetch nearby 500 stores in the same city and do some processing on the 500 stores. The end result would be (store, [500 nearby processed stores])

Comment: I'd still do a keyBy, groupByKey, flatMap to get there.  I'd also change the title of your question, since this really isn't about Broadcast variable max size.

Answer (score 2):

~2GB is the max size for a broadcast variable due to any broadcast variable becomes a java byte array during serialization and java arrays have max size Integer.MAX_VALUE.

These are older (similar) questions that also pertain to PySpark 2.x

[Is there any limit on size of a spark broadcast variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021419/is-there-any-limit-on-size-of-a-spark-broadcast-variable)

[Evaluate the max size for a spark broadcast variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226163/evaluate-the-max-size-for-a-spark-broadcast-variable)

JIRA for tracking this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235

EDIT:
Use SparkSession + DataFrame (since this is PySpark - presumably 2.x) doing joins as follows.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("stores.json")
nearest_stores_df = df.join(df, "city") # self-join
```

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. But do you have any idea how do I solve the above problem?

Comment: Yes. 1) use SparkSession + DataFrame or Dataset, 2) Create a table for the stores and do a join on city instead of the high cost of broadcasting

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment above with details about what you're really trying to accomplish.

I don't use python in spark, but in scala I would start out like this.  Most of the important stuff is spark-specific and should be easy to convert to python.

Class for store:

```
class Store(val id: String, 
            val city: String, 
            val lat: Double, 
            val lon: Double) extends Haversine {

  // distance in km 
  def distance(that: Store) = {
    val radius = 6371 // earth in km 
    val dlat = toRadians(that.lat - this.lat)
    val dlon = toRadians(that.lon - this.lon)
    val a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) +
            cos(toRadians(this.lat)) * cos(toRadians(that.lat)) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
    val c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    val d = radius * c 
    d 
  }
}
```

Since you're using python anyway, i'll leave it to you to get your JSON parsed into your class.

```
// read JSON into class Store
val rdd_store: RDD[Store] = ???
```

Here's the important part...  mine would look something like this until I got it debugged...  but then I'd move the hard-to-read parts into helper functions or classes if I were going to use it for real.

```
// result
val rdd2: RDD[(Store, List[Store])] = {
  rdd_store
  .keyBy(_.city)                               // RDD[(city, store)]               (one row per store)
  .groupByKey                                  // RDD[(city, all stores in city)]  (one row per city)
  .flatMap { case (city, iter_stores) =>
    iter_stores.map(one_store => {
      // up-to 500 closest stores in same city as 'one_store'
      val top500: List[Store] = {
        iter_stores
        .toList
        .map { s => 
          val dist = one_store distance s
          (dist, s)
        }
      }.sorted.take(500).map{ case (dist, that_store) => that_store }

      // result
      (one_store, top500)
    })
  }                                           // RDD[(store, list of top 500 stores in same city)] (one row per store)
}
```

Comment: Ok. This is really helpful. Thank you very much.  Another suggestion please: If the city doesn't have 500 stores, I have a another file that says which cities to pick to get to 500 stores. How could I do that.