# PySpark - How to Increase Broadcast variable size limit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am unable to send broadcast variable of size more than 1MB to udf. Here is the code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
import numpy as np

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext    
   
    d = [('Alice', 10), ('bob', 21), ('Met', 25), ('Andy', 27)] # data frame rows
    df = spark.createDataFrame(d , ["name", "age"])   

    l = [50000] * np.ones((1300, 100))
    rdd = sc.parallelize(l)     
    
    b_rdd = sc.broadcast(rdd.collect())

    def test (x, data):
        print(x)
        print(len(data))
        
    def udf_test(data):
        return udf(lambda x : test(x, data))

    df.withColumn("test", udf_test(b_rdd.value)(col("age"))).show()
    

    spark.stop()
```

when i run this:

```
Submit-Job.cmd --master spark://xx.xx.0.24:7077 --executor-memory=20G test_2.py
```

I get the below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\h230236\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-dceed17c-fc67-43cb-9e99-69571cd36020\executor-33071657-26d7-4e89-b55a-9a8bc58b471e\spark-a184bb5a-9632-48ad-8364-99d53a0b398a\broadcast1428986508512125101' after copy to 'C:\Users\h230236\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-dceed17c-fc67-43cb-9e99-69571cd36020\executor-33071657-26d7-4e89-b55a-9a8bc58b471e\blockmgr-852e475e-890c-417d-88c3-0ed25b77e4dc\39\broadcast_2_python'
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2835)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.moveFileToBlock(DiskStore.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$TempFileBasedBlockStoreUpdater.saveToDiskStore(BlockManager.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$BlockStoreUpdater.$anonfun$save$1(BlockManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$BlockStoreUpdater.save(BlockManager.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$TempFileBasedBlockStoreUpdater.save(BlockManager.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonBroadcast.$anonfun$readObject$2(PythonRDD.scala:771)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonBroadcast.$anonfun$readObject$1(PythonRDD.scala:773)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1343)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonBroadcast.readObject(PythonRDD.scala:760)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.$anonfun$unBlockifyObject$4(TorrentBroadcast.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unBlockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$4(TorrentBroadcast.scala:249)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$2(TorrentBroadcast.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.KeyLock.withLock(KeyLock.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1(TorrentBroadcast.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1343)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$20(PythonRunner.scala:374)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:218)
20/11/06 17:01:04 ERROR PythonUDFRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\NMR_PySpark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 467, in main
  File "C:\NMR_PySpark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 595, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\h230236\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-dceed17c-fc67-43cb-9e99-69571cd36020\executor-33071657-26d7-4e89-b55a-9a8bc58b471e\spark-a184bb5a-9632-48ad-8364-99d53a0b398a\broadcast1428986508512125101' after copy to 'C:\Users\h230236\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-dceed17c-fc67-43cb-9e99-69571cd36020\executor-33071657-26d7-4e89-b55a-9a8bc58b471e\blockmgr-852e475e-890c-417d-88c3-0ed25b77e4dc\39\broadcast_2_python'
```

However if I use this data to broadcast

```
 l = [50000] * np.ones((1200, 100))
```

which is less than 1MB, and it runs with no error.

```
+-----+---+----+
| name|age|test|
+-----+---+----+
|Alice| 10|null|
|  bob| 21|null|
|  Met| 25|null|
| Andy| 27|null|
+-----+---+----+
```

Can you please help me to increase the broadcast variable size limit
I tried with this option, but didn't help

```
Submit-Job.cmd --master spark://xx.xx.0.24:7077 --executor-memory=20G --conf spark.broadcast.blockSize=100m test_1.py
```

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that this job failed due to failure in deleting some old files. Could you clean up the errored path to try again?

The default size of broadcast variable is 2GB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226163/evaluate-the-max-size-for-a-spark-broadcast-variable

The auto broadcast size setting is below, may change with spark version.
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold, 10485760 (10 MB),
This setting is used while making physical plan to decide if broadcast join is possible.

Comment: Yes, stacktrace says failed to delete file, not unable to understand the error.  I cleandup %temp% folder and gave full rights, even then when i run i got the same error. I wonder how spark is writing broadcast variable to temp folder when broad cast variable size is less than 1MB.

Comment: Actual error is hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 595, in read_int raise EOFError EOFError

Comment: with complete log

Comment: One question, why are you broadcasting a list of elements (from `rdd.collect()`)? The `collect()` won't return an rdd, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: In this example, i wanted to demonstrate, iam getting error if broadcast variable of having more than 1MB, its easy to demonstrate with the list. In actual scenario, i have dictionary of complex structure where in i need to use in udf to process whole data frame.,